# Android Consent Information publisher misconfiguration

Tags: java, android, admob, gdprconsentform, user-messaging-platform

I try to use Google Consent with the User Messaging Platform to show in Android app consent form. I follow this documentation https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start.

I get this error:

```
onConsentInfoUpdateFailure: Publisher misconfiguration: Failed to read publisher's account configuration; please check your configured app ID. Received app ID: `ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX`.
```

My Code:

```
ConsentRequestParameters params;

    if (testingGDPR) {

        ConsentDebugSettings debugSettings = new ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(this)
                .setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings.DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
                .addTestDeviceHashedId(getString(R.string.ADMOB_REAL_DEVICE_HASH_ID_FOR_TESTING))
                .build();

        params = new ConsentRequestParameters.Builder().setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings).build();
    } else {
        params = new ConsentRequestParameters.Builder().build();
    }

    consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);

    if (testingGDPR) {
        consentInformation.reset();
    }

    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
            this,
            params,
            new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {
                    
                    if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable() && consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                        loadForm();
                    } else {
                        setupAds();
                    }
                }
            },
            new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError) {
                    Log.d("gdpr", "onConsentInfoUpdateFailure, code:" + formError.getErrorCode() + ", " + formError.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Comment: is Funding Choices account linked to your AdMob account.?

Comment: @AmodGokhale Yes, I already link it and set up the Blocking Control in Admob.

Comment: Have you settled the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The TestDeviceHashedId is not the same thing as the Admob Device Id.
So remove this line:

```
.addTestDeviceHashedId(getString(R.string.ADMOB_REAL_DEVICE_HASH_ID_FOR_TESTING))
```

Then run your code and check for the log. The TestDeviceHashedId you should use will appear.